# How to write vritual destructors with multilevel inheritance?

Tags: c++

I'd like to know what's the correct way to implement virtual destructors when dealing with multilevel inheritance.

So let me introduce this simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A {

  virtual ~A() { cout << "~A()" << endl; }

};

struct B : A {
  ~B() { cout << "~B()" << endl; }
};

struct C : B {
  ~C() { cout << "~C()" << endl;  }
};

struct D : B {
  ~D() { cout << "~D()" << endl; }
};

int main() {
  A* a = new C();
  B* b = new D();
  delete a;
  delete b;
}
```

So afaik, when the base class declares its destructor as virtual it will call correctly the destructor of its children when it gets deleted. My concern is that when I ran this code in both cases **delete a** and **delete b**, the children were destroyed correctly, while I was spectating that only delete a would achieve that.

Is this the correct behavior? If so, does it mean that every child class of A will declare its destructor as virtual even if it's not explicitly specified and I can safely assume they will be deleted correctly?

Comment: (I hope that's what you're asking) Once a function is `virtual`, you cannot make it non-`virtual` anywhere in the inheritance tree. This is especially important for destructors : if only `B`'s destructor was allowed to run, `A` would never be able to clean up its own stuff.

Comment: Alright, thanks I wasn't sure about that.

Comment: Also, when writing new code, please [refrain from using new and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new).

Comment: Ikr, but currently I'm working with Qt so I don't really have other options.

Comment: Like they said, there's no need to put `virtual` again. But it's good practice to do so with every virtual function and preferably if it's C++11 onwards to put `override`.

Comment: FWIW, Qt does not prevent you from using `unique_ptr`. Not for the GUI hierarchy itself, but all other objects.

Comment: A virtual function (destructor included) means that the **object type** will be used to determine what to call.   A non-virtual function uses the **variable type** to determine what function to call.   If you inherit from something with a virtual function, then you have that same virtual function.